# using Bootstrap want to make responsive two columns form

Tags: css, forms, mobile, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have a two column form like this in desktop

```
|A|B|
|C|D|
|E|F|
```

and I want that in mobile

```
|A|
|B|
|C|
|D|
|E|
|F|
```

But i'm getting

```
|A|
|C|
|E|
|B|
|D|
|F|
```

My code is like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <input> <!-- A -->
      <input> <!-- C -->
      <input> <!-- D -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ">
      <input> <!-- B -->
      <input> <!-- D -->
      <input> <!-- F -->
    </div>
</div>
```

please can you help

Comment: i use col-sm-12 and col-md-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            A
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            C
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            D
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            E
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            F
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but nested cols should be places inside another `.row`

Answer (score 2):

Going with your original code, put a class for each `input`, or one `div` per `input`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    D
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    E
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    F
  </div>
</div>
```